# using dajaxice and editlive apps in django

Tags: django, django-apps, dajaxice

So I am pretty new to Django and I am a little confused on how to install apps.
I am trying to get the editlive app to work in Django. This requires dajaxice to also be installed. Both of the instructions for this are very similar, basically it says to change some things in *settings.py*, *urls.py*, and add some imports to your *main.html*.

I did these things, but the instructions don't say what I am supposed to do with the dajaxice, and editlive packages. In each package there is a *install.py*, should I build and run this? Or am I supposed to just include all the code in with my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python/django community uses a tool called pip to install python packages and libraries. Look up [how to install pip](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html) on your system (and also look up virtualenv), and then you can simply do:

`pip install django-dajaxice`

`pip install django-editlive`

Comment: Awesome I will try that. Do I need to be in my project directory when I call this or does it matter?

Comment: If you just use pip without virtualenv (virtualenv is highly recommended), you would just do "sudo pip install ...", and then those packages are on your python path. You can run that command anywhere, and use the packages anywhere

Comment: dajaxice installed fine, but when I try to install editlive i get this error

No distributions at all found for django-editlive

So maybe it's not in the pip repository or something?
Is there any alternative way you know of?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Ah good point, editlive is not in the pip repository. Luckily you can use pip to install from github, like so: `pip install git+https://github.com/h3/django-editlive.git`